# How to tell what events are bound to an input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug

I ran across a site where during registration, the input field for the nickname won't let me type in more characters and/or change focus to a different input field, while it is using a jQuery AJAX call to check if the nickname is available.

Just for fun I decided I want to get to the bottom of it.
I thought this would be an easy task but I was wrong.

I can't seem to find what causes it using Firebug.
How can I see all events that are bound or get fired off when I type something?

Comment: Can you post a link to the field you are talking about?

Comment: http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2

Comment: Just return false on key events and focus events while the ajax call is running ?

Comment: https://esagamer.com/register when you click create an account, notice what happens in the "Player Name:"